# Minecraft Modding: Issue with blockstate not being able to work

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

So, I was trying to make a mod that adds a "workshop" block and I thought it would be great if it visually behaved like a vanilla furnace but with different textures. I've used vanilla blockstate for such result and I've ended up with it throwing `blockstate location exception`.

Blockstate file:

```
{ 
    "variants": { 
        "facing=north": { "model": "magicmod:block/workshop" },
        "facing=south": { "model": "magicmod:block/workshop", "y": 180 },
        "facing=west":  { "model": "magicmod:block/workshop", "y": 270 },
        "facing=east":  { "model": "magicmod:block/workshop", "y": 90 }
    }
}
```

Exception trace:

```
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model magicmod:workshop#normal with loader VariantLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:161) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.registerVariant(ModelLoader.java:235) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadBlock(ModelBakery.java:153) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadBlocks(ModelLoader.java:223) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:150) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:121) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:513) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86) [legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar:0.2.3.1+4+372be23]
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29) [legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar:0.2.3.1+4+372be23]
Caused by: net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$MissingVariantException
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.getVariant(ModelBlockDefinition.java:83) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VariantLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:1175) ~[ModelLoader$VariantLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:157) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    ... 21 more
```

Even using the vanilla furnace blockstate straight copypasted resulted in similar exception.
Vanilla furnace blockstate file:

```
{
    "variants": {
        "facing=north": { "model": "furnace" },
        "facing=south": { "model": "furnace", "y": 180 },
        "facing=west":  { "model": "furnace", "y": 270 },
        "facing=east":  { "model": "furnace", "y": 90 }
    }
}
```

Exception trace:

```
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model magicmod:workshop#inventory with loader VariantLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:161) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:296) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:151) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:121) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:513) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86) [legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar:0.2.3.1+4+372be23]
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29) [legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar:0.2.3.1+4+372be23]
Caused by: net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$MissingVariantException
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.getVariant(ModelBlockDefinition.java:83) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VariantLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:1175) ~[ModelLoader$VariantLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:157) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    ... 20 more
```

full logs: https://gist.github.com/deeg05/d180a7fda9886d7aa1ed9ae48b736b06

Comment: Oh! I just got it! I need additional code for such metadata to be in block!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I did it by adding all the necessary code for block metadata.